# How to convert ng select to md-select

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have old code for ng-select

```
<ng-select
    [active]="cntry"
    [items]="countryList"
    (data)="refreshCountryValue($event)"
    placeholder="{{ezzy.LOCALIZATION.cntry}}"></ng-select>
```

I want to convert it into `md-select`

```
<md-select placeholder="Country" >
   <md-option></md-option>
</md-select>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This shoild get you going, https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview